# Controlling form elements from a different thread in Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, forms, windows-mobile

Trying to get a thread to change form controls in Windows Mobile.

Throws an unsupported exception.

Does this mean it cant be done at all?

If not, how do I go about this? Forms are created in the Parent/Main thread then a thread is created to do some work in the background but I want to make it so the Background thread can update the form to show its completed...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update UI from multiple worker threads (.NET)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097284/update-ui-from-multiple-worker-threads-net)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot access GUI items on a non-GUI thread. You will need to determine if an invocation is required to the GUI thread. For example (here's some I made earlier):

```
public delegate void SetEnabledStateCallBack(Control control, bool enabled);
public static void SetEnabledState(Control control, bool enabled)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetEnabledStateCallBack d = new SetEnabledStateCallBack(SetEnabledState);
        control.Invoke(d, new object[] { control, enabled });
    }
    else
    {
        control.Enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

Or

```
public delegate void AddListViewItemCallBack(ListView control, ListViewItem item);
public static void AddListViewItem(ListView control, ListViewItem item)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        AddListViewItemCallBack d = new AddListViewItemCallBack(AddListViewItem);
        control.Invoke(d, new object[] { control, item });
    }
    else
    {
        control.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

You can then set the enabled property (from my first example) using `ClassName.SetEnabledState(this, true);`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the [`Control.InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(VS.85).aspx) property as UI elements must be accessed from the main thread.

In your background thread you raise an event.

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyApp_MyEvent;

this.MyApp_MyEvent(this, new MyEventArgs(MyArg));
```

In you main UI thread you subscribe to that event:

```
this.myThread.MyApp_MyEvent+= this.MyAppEventHandler;
```

and the handler itself:

```
private void MyApp_EventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.MyControl.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.MyControl.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { this.MyAction(e.MyArg); });
    }
    else
    {
        this.MyAction(e.MyArg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of professional curiosity: I believe your answer and my answer are pretty much the same except you're using an EventHandler (which is a delegate right?) and I'm using delegates. What's the benefit of using EventHandlers over delegate methods?

Comment: @Generic - that's a good question. This is the way I've done it in a number of applications and I'm afraid it's one of those cases where I found something that works and I basically understand how it works so I've never had the need to investigate further. First link that turned up was this http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000040.html

Comment: That's the same reason I use delegates methods. It works, always has, so I've never questioned it or looked into it further. I was hoping you were going to enlighten me!

Comment: @Generic: EventHandlers *are* delegates, so you're using the same mechanism. One reason you might go explicitly with an EventHandler is if you have to support CF 2.0, which only allows you to Invoke an EventHandler-type delegate.

Answer (score 0):

See Also:

- [Force Multi-threaded VB.NET Class to Dsplay Results on a Single Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273639/force-multi-threaded-vb-net-class-to-display-results-on-a-single-form)
- [Bring data came from async operation to main thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846832/bring-data-came-from-async-operation-to-main-thread)
- [Update UI from multiple worker threads (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097284/update-ui-from-multiple-worker-threads-net)
- [C# Thread issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579854/c-thread-issues)
- [How can you tell if you’re on the Main UI thread? (In CF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825373/how-can-you-tell-if-youre-on-the-main-ui-thread-in-cf/841335)
- [Separation of GUI and logic in different threads in a Windows Form application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333566/separation-of-gui-and-logic-in-different-threads-in-a-windows-form-application/1333638)